# character is not moving in scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Hey i have imported my character animation in xcode and i want to move it with touch in scenekit let suppose from point A to another point B . but it is not moving i have the following code. don,t know why it is not working please help....thanks

```
//character imported from blender
var scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/hero.dae")!
// touches for movement 
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    var taps = event!.allTouches()
    touchCount = taps?.count
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    touchCount = 0


}

func positionCameraWithHero() {
    let hero = heroNode.presentationNode
    var heroPosition = hero.position
    let cameraDamping:Float = 0.3
    var targetPosition = SCNVector3Make(heroPosition.x, 30.0, heroPosition.z + 20.0)
    var cameraPosition = camera.position
    var cameraXPos = cameraPosition.x * (1.0 - cameraDamping) + targetPosition.x *
cameraDamping
    var cameraYPos = cameraPosition.y * (1.0 - cameraDamping) + targetPosition.y *
cameraDamping
    var cameraZPos = cameraPosition.z * (1.0 - cameraDamping) + targetPosition.z *
cameraDamping
    cameraPosition = SCNVector3(x: cameraXPos, y: cameraYPos, z: cameraZPos)
    camera.position = cameraPosition
    light.position = SCNVector3(x: heroPosition.x, y: 90, z: heroPosition.z +
    40.0)
    light.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: Float(-M_PI/2.8))

}

func renderer(aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {
    let moveDistance = Float(10.0)
    let moveSpeed = NSTimeInterval(1.0)
    let currentX = heroNode.position.x
    let currentY = heroNode.position.y
    let currentZ = heroNode.position.z

    if touchCount == 1{
        let action = SCNAction.moveTo(SCNVector3Make(currentX, currentY, currentZ -
        moveDistance), duration: moveSpeed);
        heroNode.runAction(action)
    }
    else if touchCount == 2 {
        let action = SCNAction.moveTo(SCNVector3Make(currentX, currentY, currentZ +
        moveDistance), duration: moveSpeed)
        heroNode.runAction(action)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is attempting to create and run a new SCNAction each time a frame is rendered. That's likely not what you want.

Instead, create one SCNAction when the touch is received, with a duration of, say 10 seconds. Run that. That code belongs in `touchesBegan()` (or maybe `touchesEnded()`).

You can make your code a bit shorter by using `SCNAction.moveBy(_:duration:)` or `SCNAction.moveByX(_:y:z:duration:)` instead of `moveTo()`. What you're calling `moveSpeed` is really a time interval, not a speed, and that terminology could be confusing to future maintainers.

I don't see that `positionCameraWithHero()` is ever called. It should be invoked from `renderer(didSimulatePhysicsAtTime:)`.

Note: in your current implementation, `renderer(didSimulatePhysicsAtTime{)` will never be invoked. That's because you have no animations running (see [SKScene becomes unresponsive while being idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141782/skscene-becomes-unresponsive-while-being-idle/28147965#28147965)). Also be aware of an apparent bug in the `playing` property being ignored on OS X (see [SceneKit SCNSceneRendererDelegate - renderer function not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390959/scenekit-scnscenerendererdelegate-renderer-function-not-called/35399224?noredirect=1#comment58613351_35399224)). However, once you've corrected the creation of the SCNAction, you won't have this issue.